# MS Publisher 2007 - Start numbering on page 3

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-publisher, microsoft-office

Is it possible to adjust the starting page for the automatic numbering in MS Publisher 2007.

I'm trying to get 'Page 1' to display on the bottom of my third actual page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use sections to do this. See 
[Microsoft Publisher help on breaking a document into sections to restart page numbering or start on a particular page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher-help/format-page-numbers-HP006281386.aspx).

> On the Insert menu, click Section. 
>   Select the Begin a section with this page check box.